# How to use Encode with html textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use the Html.Encode by replacing Name <%=Html.TextBox("Name", Model.projectModel.Name)%>

However, since i`m using jquery, How I can still keep the name of the texbox?

Is it possible to use Html.encode and still keep the name of the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Name", Html.Encode(Model.projectModel.Name)) %>
```